# Scrollable grid in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to javafx. My task is to make several graphs in one window. But the problem is that there are too many of them and they do not fit in the window correctly.

In other cases I used GridPane and it worked. But now I am faced with the problem described above. How can I implement a scrollable window in the likeness of a grid? If possible, provide a link to the example/documentation.

At the moment, my charts look like this. And they look acceptable. Do not pay attention to the signatures, they will be made later.

[image]

I use the GridPane to determine the position of the graphs. Here is my code:

```
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.add(lineChart0,0,0);
        pane.add(lineChart1,1,0);
        pane.add(lineChart2,2,0);
        pane.add(lineChart3,0,1);
        pane.add(lineChart4,1,1);
        pane.add(lineChart5,2,1);
        pane.add(lineChart6,3,1);
        pane.add(lineChart7,0,2);
        pane.add(lineChart8,1,2);
        pane.add(lineChart9,2,2);
        pane.add(lineChart10,3,2);
        pane.add(lineChart11,0,3);
        pane.add(lineChart12,1,3);
        pane.add(lineChart13,2,3);
        pane.add(lineChart14,3,3);


        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 1920, 1000);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
```

But now I need to add some more charts lines. When I add these lines, this happens:

[image]

Data signatures and the last chart line disappear.  Don't pay attention to the empty spaces in the grid. Here I'm just checking how charts will behave with a given number of rows.

```
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.add(lineChart0,0,0);
        pane.add(lineChart1,1,0);
        pane.add(lineChart2,2,0);
        pane.add(lineChart3,0,1);
        pane.add(lineChart4,1,1);
        pane.add(lineChart5,2,1);
        pane.add(lineChart6,3,1);
        pane.add(lineChart7,0,2);
        pane.add(lineChart8,1,2);
        pane.add(lineChart9,2,2);
        pane.add(lineChart10,3,2);
        pane.add(lineChart11,0,3);
        pane.add(lineChart12,1,4);
        pane.add(lineChart13,2,5);
        pane.add(lineChart14,3,6);


        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 1920, 1000);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
```

I need the graphs to be displayed correctly in one window. According to my idea, this can be done by scrolling the page. But maybe my idea is wrong. I tried to find an example of how to combine grid pane and scrollpane, but code  that I found doesn't work in my version of the library(17.0.2). There is no `setContent` method when I try to repeat the example. Here is an example of this code:

```
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();

GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
gridPane.add(new Label("Name:"), 0, 0);
gridPane.add(new TextField(), 1, 0);
gridPane.add(new Label("Description:"), 0, 1);
gridPane.add(new TextArea(), 1, 1);

scrollPane.setContent(gridPane);
```

Comment: The solution is to use a `ScrollPane`. In what way does the code in your question not work for you? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: The other option is to use a `ListView`, which is preferred if you have a significant number of graphs to display.

Comment: “the code I found doesn't work” —How can you tell?

Comment: You wrote in your question: _the code I found doesn't work in my version of the library_ What "library" are you referring to? Is the code in your question the code that you found?

Comment: I understand that a minimal reproducible example is needed here.  But as I said earlier I am new to javafx.  I just need to put 7 lines of charts in one window so that it looks at least not pinched. Does it make sense to add even more code here - I don't think so.  Because you certainly don't need my calculations.

Comment: "_Does it make sense to add even more code here - I don't think so._" – But we **do** think so. Or at least we think you should show your actual attempt (in the form of a [mre]). From our perspective, you have apparently already found a solution. So, we don't really understand what you're actually asking. You state using a `ScrollPane` "doesn't work". But **how** doesn't it work? What did you try? In other words, a [mre] would help us help you (plus any errors you're getting).

Comment: OK, I was wrong. Now I will add a little explanation of how it should look like.

Comment: "_There is no setContent method when I try to repeat the example_" – I think this was the piece of information we were missing. As you can see in [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#setContent(javafx.scene.Node)), that method does indeed exist and has existed since JavaFX 2.0 (which is approximately 10 major versions older than the version you're using). My guess is you erroneously imported `java.awt.ScrollPane`. But `javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane` is the class you want to import.

Comment: As a general rule, unless you really know what you're doing, avoid importing anything from the `java.awt.*` or `java.swing.*` packages when creating a JavaFX application. All code related to the JavaFX standard library is in packages starting with `javafx.*`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The example did not say that you need to use ``javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane``. And Intellij IDEA suggested importing the wrong class. Thanks for the help.